# Visual Studio 2008 Does Not Show Events Button in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have created an ASP.NET page that derives from Master Page. The page includes LoginView control. When I put button inside LoggedInTemplate Visual studio does not show available events for the button. I cannot add any handlers automatically. The type of the button changes from .NET class to just .

I can only add that for some inexplpainable reason it appears after the control is viewed and clicked on in designer view.

Any ideas?

The hierarchy:-

MasterPage.master
+-ContentPage.aspx
_+-LoginView
**+-LoggedInTemplate 
_**+-   <----- CANNOT ADD EVENTS (LIGHTNING SIGN DOES NOT APPEAR IN PROPERTIES)

Comment: I have the same problem in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that in Source View the events icon (the lightning bolt) doesn't show up.  If I send it into Split View and click on the control in question, the lightning bolt comes back.  Annoying, but works.